# Why would I want to reference cursor.fetchall() if I can use cursor.execute directly?

Tags: python, sqlite

Why would I want to reference cursor.fetchall() if I can use cursor.execute directly?a

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `cursor.execute()` doesn't actually return the data. Presumably you need that, so you need to run `fetchall`.

Comment: Ahn, I understand now, it just doesn't "return". although I can use it in a loop. Ok. Thank you!